# Create Multiple subfolder in Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program to create a multiple folder and 2 folders in each folder created. As per the below program I am able to create 1 subfolder only.

```
import os
root_path="C:\\Users\\Master\\Desktop\\SERIAL"
for i in range(20180812, 20180818):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_path, str(i), 'name'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more folders into your loop:

```
import os

root_path = "./"
subsfolders_to_create = ['name','age','size']

for i in range(20180812, 20180818):
    for subfolder in subsfolders_to_create :
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(root_path, str(i), subfolder))

for root,dirs,files in os.walk("./"):
    for d in dirs:
        print (os.path.join(root,d))
```

Output:

```
./20180813
./20180814
./20180815
./20180812
./20180816
./20180817
./20180813/size
./20180813/age
./20180813/name
./20180814/size
./20180814/age
./20180814/name
./20180815/size
./20180815/age
./20180815/name
./20180812/size
./20180812/age
./20180812/name
./20180816/size
./20180816/age
./20180816/name
./20180817/size
./20180817/age
./20180817/name
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering. The response is correct as per the code you provided.